# this code raise run time exception

Tags: android

**This code is to get account from mobile in application**

```
package com.example.lenovo.email;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String[] userEmailId = null;
    private static String mDeviceId = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        String[] email_a=null;
        email_a=setUserEmailId(this);
        if(email_a == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("null");
        }
        else {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, email_a);
            dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            // edit.setText(setUserEmailId(this));
        }

    }
  //used to get accounts in dropdown list
    private static String[] setUserEmailId(Context mContext) {
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(mContext).getAccounts();
int i=0;
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                userEmailId[i] = account.name;
                Log.d("Email",userEmailId[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        return  userEmailId;
    }

}
```

Code gives run time exception.
When I run this code unfortunately application has been stopped.
I can't resolve this exception .....

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to edit your question as per: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You must also include the logcat details when asking questions about crashes

Comment: please share your logcat

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't initialized `userEmailId` properly, it is still `null` when you're trying to add elements to it.

I'd suggest you to use an `ArrayList` instead of a `String` array:

```
private List<String> getUserEmailId(Context context) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            list.add(account.name);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you using `RuntimeException` without resolve it? I mean you need to catch exception then do something with it :)

I think `setUserEmailId` method return null. Let check logic of code trying to find email. Need to use *Logcat* when you didn't find email, `RuntimeException` is main reason to force app stop :)

```
if(email_a == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("null");
}
```